# Xcode command line tools install failing due to network error

Tags: macos, install, xcode

After upgrading macOS one has to re-install the command line tools for Xcode. But when I try I get the license agreement and hit "Agree" and then I get a popup saying that "install failed because of a network error" and no hint as to what actually happened.

No other network issues that I can find.

I looked in the logs but did not find anything relevant, nor did Google fid anything so this does not appear to be a widespread issue.